# Вид QPushButton как в дизайнере

Tags: c++, qt, gui, ui, интерфейс

Как сделать `QPushButton` в таком виде, в котором `QPushButton` есть в дизайнере. То есть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я имею такой код:

```
ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {"
                                      "background-color: lightGray;"
                                      "border-style: solid;"
                                      "border-width: 5px;"
                                      "border-radius: 15px;"
                                      "border-color: red;"
                                      "padding: 10px;"
                              "}");
```

Может как-то через **margin** сделать?
Мне нужно отобразить этих 8 квадратиков вокруг кнопки.

Comment: Полагаю, что нарисовать квадратики стилями не получится. Придётся кнопку самому рисовать полностью

Answer (score 1):

Наследуйте от `QPushButton` и переопределяйте `paintEvent`, чтобы нарисовать такие кубики, поскольку эти кубики являются эффектом выделения элемента в дизайнере, позволяющие манипулировать геометрией объекта.